# ffmpeg youtube livestream stops after a while

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, http-live-streaming

I'll update this question

ffmpeg -version

```sh
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-4ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-9ubuntu2)
```

I run this command to use ffmpeg to stream to youtube ;

```sh
ffmpeg -y -threads 12 \
-loop 1 -framerate 30 -re \
-i ./1280x720.jpg \
-i ./audio.mp3 \
-video_size 1280x720 \
-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-b:v 4500k -maxrate 5500k -bufsize 22000k \
-preset ultrafast -crf 23 -tune stillimage \
-b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec aac \
-filter_complex "dynaudnorm=f=150:g=15" \
-r 30 -g 60 \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx 2>&1 | tee _LOG
```

The stream is excellent for 45-53 minutes then i'll get an error like this from ffmpeg:

```sh
[flv @ 0x56077027cd80] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10034000 > 10000000: forcing output
```

then youtube starts to say, no data being received and the stream will end, which it does.

This is the full log: http://0x0.st/-zUH.txt

Comment: the log is 41M, where can I upload that?

Comment: I updated the question with a full log file.

Comment: I updated the question, providing ffmpeg version, rerunning the command and doing a full log. Please take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MP3 duration is `00:49:57.42` so the stream messes up after it ends. Loop the audio with `-stream_loop -1` and add `-re` for real-time reading of the input:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-loop 1 -framerate 30 -re -i ./1280x720.jpg \
-re -stream_loop -1 -i ./audio.mp3 \
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-b:v 4500k -maxrate 5500k -bufsize 22000k \
-preset ultrafast -tune stillimage \
-b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:a aac \
-filter_complex "dynaudnorm=f=150:g=15" \
-g 60 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx
```

Alternatively, remove `-re -stream_loop -1` and add the output option `-shortest` if you want the stream to end when the audio ends.

Unrelated changes:

- No need to set `-threads`. Let `ffmpeg` auto choose.
- `-video_size 1280x720` is an input option for certain demuxers and does nothing in your command. Removed. Your input is already 1280x720 anyway: otherwise, see [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit a specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305/110524).
- `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive. In your case `-b:v` is being ignored. For streaming you probably want to use `-b:v`. Removed `-crf`.
- You already set the frame rate with `-framerate 30` so `-r 30` is not needed. Removed.
- Recommend using the slowest `-preset` that still encodes fast enough.